# While IF in Python - Looping if statements are incorrect

Tags: python

Having some difficulty using a While function alongside an IF so that if an INPUT hasn't been met, the same question would be repeatedly asked until the outcome was correct.

```
county = input(str("County London/Kent/Essex: ")).upper()
while county != ("LONDON") and county != ("KENT") and county != ("ESSEX"):
    if county == ("LONDON"):
        county = ("LONDON")
    elif county == ("KENT"):
        county = ("KENT")
    elif county == ("ESSEX"):
        county = ("ESSEX")
    else:
        county = input(str("Invalid - Please enter an accepted county: ")).upper()
```

If the user doesn't enter London, Kent or Essex, the input message would be asked until one of these are entered.

Comment: As a side suggestion, you can use `while county not in ["LONDON","KENT","ESSEX"]:`

Comment: For performance while `county not in ("LONDON","KENT","ESSEX"):` is slightly better ;)

Comment: what are you asking? I ran your code and it worked as you would think. The loop keeps prompting and exits once one of the three places are input.

Comment: `county = ("ESSEX")` evaluates into `county = "ESSEX"` without brackets. Do ypu need to make a tuple? If yes, use `county = ("ESSEX", )`

Comment: @Dmitry Lists and tuples both have O(n) `in` operators. I think you want the set `{"LONDON", "KENT", "ESSEX"}` for O(1) operations.

Comment: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482) may be of interest to you. (Not voting to close as duplicate since your question is more "why isn't this specific code working?" than "what's a good way to do this?")

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? The Python 2 `input` function is rather different to the one in Python 3 and should be avoided.

Comment: @chepner i know about complexity issues. But your answer is wrong. In a case of small objects `tuple` is more faster, check it using `timeit`: `python -m timeit 'from random import choice' 'a = choice(["London", "Kent", "Essex"])' 'if a in ("LONDON","KENT","ESSEX"): pass'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 usec per loop; python -m timeit 'from random import choice' 'a = choice(["London", "Kent", "Essex"])' 'if a in {"LONDON","KENT","ESSEX"}: pass'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 usec per loop`. In a case of large objects `set` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess. You are getting an error like

```
NameError: name 'London' is not defined
```

The reason for that is the following: `input` treats what it reads as Python expression, not as string; so when you enter `London` it tries to interpret it as the variable name named `London`. Try to enter string instead: `"London"` -- and it will work.

Example of what `input` does:

```
>>> print input("-> ")
-> [1, 2, 3][0] + 4
5
```

It's 5 because `input` treats what it reads as Python exrpession. In this case it sees the list of three numbers, takes the first one and adds 4 to it.

You really should not use `input()`. Do the following:

```
import sys
...
...
else:
    print "some prompt goes here"
    line = sys.stdin.readline().strip().upper()
```

**Edit:** as mentioned in the comment, it's even better to use `raw_input()` instead of `sys.stdin.readline()`. Completely forgot about it; did not write programs which read from terminal from quite some time :)

Comment: `raw_input("some prompt goes here")` would be the first choice before `sys.stdin.readline()`.

Comment: Indeed. Will add a note to the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
counties = ["London", "Kent", "Essex"] # list of counties
prompt = "County " + "/".join(counties) + ": " # prompt of the input

while True:
    county = raw_input(prompt).title() # using str.title to format the input
    if county in counties: # the input is part of the list
        county = county.upper()
        break
    else: # the input is invalid, try again 
        print "Invalid - Please enter an accepted county."
```

Note: I used `raw_input()` instead of `input()`

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Python 3 instead of 2, the code runs smoothly as is.

They changed `input()` not to evaluate the input as a python expression in 3.4, to work like the old `raw_input()`.

Here's the docs for [python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> input([prompt])
>
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. Other exceptions
>   may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.
>
> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.
>
> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

and [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input):

> input([prompt])
>
> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from
>   input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and
>   returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised. Example:
>
> ```
> >>> s = input('--> ')  
> --> Monty Python's Flying Circus
> >>> s  
> "Monty Python's Flying Circus"
> ```
>
> If the readline module was loaded, then input() will use it to provide elaborate line editing and history features.